# Is there a possibility to apply different regex var depending on if statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, prestashop

I'm trying to write a function that validates number depending on the country. With each country, using intl-input, I obtain different class. Depending on that class inside the PrestaShop checkout module I am trying to implement the different amount of characters in phone input.

Result is something like this:

```
function validatePhoneNumber(s)
{
    if ($('div').hasClass("opt216")) {
        var reg = /^\+(?:[0-9] ?){10}$/;

    }else {
        var reg = /^\+(?:[0-9] ?){10,14}$/;

    }
    return reg.test(s);
}
```

What I have in this is every country has the same amount of characters (10) and if the statement doesn't seem to work. So, I thinking, is making this regex variable and changing it on if statement actually allowed?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bygd9e42/  There's nothing wrong with declaring variables inside the if.  `var` is not block scoped.  `let` is block scoped, but you are not using `let`.  You can make an argument that it is not the cleanest approach, but it *does work*

Comment: For which data is it not working?

Comment: "if statement doesn't seem to work" -- for what input do you see unexpected results? Your code appears to work for me.

Comment: i have this input type="tel" field, that should change based on hasClass option. I don't think i could put whole code in fiddle, but if you add to cart some product here - https://testvideo.alunika.com/ - and go to checkout (https://testvideo.alunika.com/module/supercheckout/supercheckout), you'll see, that changing phone code from ukraine to other country will not trigger change in characters amount.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input, it's free / open-source, cross-browser and will work well with PrestaShop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I figured out what was wrong - i had few opt216 classes in document, so i went another way with attribute selection, something like that

```
if ($('#iti-item-216').attr('aria-selected') == 'true')
```